# spring-boot disable HTTP methods

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-boot

For Tomcat it's fairly easy to disable certain HTTP methods. Just add to the web.xml:

```
    <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>restricted methods</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>PUT</http-method>
        <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
        <http-method>HEAD</http-method>
        <http-method>OPTIONS</http-method>
        <http-method>TRACE</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint/>
</security-constraint>
```

How do I do the same in spring-boot? 
 I've tried adding the following:

```
@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer containerCustomizer() {
    return new EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer() {
        @Override
        public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {
            if (container.getClass().isAssignableFrom(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.class)) {
                TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcatContainer = (TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) container;
                tomcatContainer.addContextCustomizers(new ContextSecurityCustomizer());
            }
        }
    };
}

private static class ContextSecurityCustomizer implements TomcatContextCustomizer {
    @Override
    public void customize(Context context) {
        SecurityConstraint constraint = new SecurityConstraint();
        SecurityCollection securityCollection = new SecurityCollection();
        securityCollection.setName("restricted_methods");
        securityCollection.addPattern("/*");
        securityCollection.addMethod(HttpMethod.DELETE.toString());
        constraint.addCollection(securityCollection);
        context.addConstraint(constraint);
    }
}
```

with little success. The `EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer` bean is created, however I can still issue DELETE requests.
 Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2):

```
//Restrict all method except GET & POST Spring boot
@Configuration
public class TomcatCustomizer implements EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer {

    @Override
    public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {
        TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcat = (TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) container;
        tomcat.setSessionTimeout(8, TimeUnit.HOURS);
        tomcat.addContextCustomizers(new ContextSecurityCustomizer());

    }
    private static class ContextSecurityCustomizer implements TomcatContextCustomizer {
        @Override
        public void customize(Context context) {
            SecurityConstraint constraint = new SecurityConstraint();
            SecurityCollection securityCollection = new SecurityCollection();
            securityCollection.setName("restricted_methods");
            securityCollection.addPattern("/*");
            securityCollection.addOmittedMethod(HttpMethod.POST.toString());
            securityCollection.addOmittedMethod(HttpMethod.GET.toString());
            constraint.addCollection(securityCollection);
            constraint.setAuthConstraint(true);
            context.addConstraint(constraint);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: While a block of code might provide a quick solution, it is more helpful to break it down and explain the parts that lead to the answer. Please add comments that can teach about the structure of your solution.

Answer (score 1):

That happens when you forget to add:

```
constraint.setAuthConstraint(true);
```

Working now !

Comment: Do you know equivalent to tomcat in jetty ?