# Disable http TRACK/TRACE in undertow using spring boot

Tags: java, spring, http, spring-boot, undertow

I want to disable http TRACE in undertow. I am using spring boot and undertow is provided with it by default. I have excluded tomcat and using undertow. I got the answer for tomcat in other stackoverflow post ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35133942/spring-boot-disable-http-methods)) but I am unable to find the same for undertow. This is what I have done till now.

```
    @Bean
    public EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer containerCustomizer() {
        return new EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer() {
            @Override
            public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {
                if (container.getClass().isAssignableFrom(UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.class)) {
                    UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory underTowContainer = (UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) container;
                    underTowContainer.addDeploymentInfoCustomizers(new ContextSecurityCustomizer());
                }
            }
        };
    }

    private static class ContextSecurityCustomizer implements UndertowDeploymentInfoCustomizer {
        @Override
        public void customize(DeploymentInfo deploymentInfo) {
            DeploymentInfo info = new DeploymentInfo();
            // What next after this
        }
    }
```

Please help me complete this code. Am I even moving in the right direction? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for undertow:

```
@Bean
    public EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer containerCustomizer() {
        return new EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer() {
            @Override
            public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {
                if (container.getClass().isAssignableFrom(UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.class)) {
                    UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory undertowContainer = (UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) container;
                    undertowContainer.addDeploymentInfoCustomizers(new ContextSecurityCustomizer());
                }
            }
        };
    }

    private static class ContextSecurityCustomizer implements UndertowDeploymentInfoCustomizer {

        @Override
        public void customize(io.undertow.servlet.api.DeploymentInfo deploymentInfo) {
            SecurityConstraint constraint = new SecurityConstraint();
            WebResourceCollection traceWebresource = new WebResourceCollection();
            traceWebresource.addUrlPattern("/*");
            traceWebresource.addHttpMethod(HttpMethod.TRACE.toString());
            constraint.addWebResourceCollection(traceWebresource);
            deploymentInfo.addSecurityConstraint(constraint);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `DisallowedMethodsHandler` from undertow:

```
import io.undertow.server.handlers.DisallowedMethodsHandler;

@Component
public class UndertowWebServerCustomizer
        implements WebServerFactoryCustomizer<UndertowServletWebServerFactory> {

    @Override
    public void customize(UndertowServletWebServerFactory factory) {

        factory.addDeploymentInfoCustomizers(deploymentInfo -> {
            deploymentInfo.addInitialHandlerChainWrapper(new HandlerWrapper() {
                @Override
                public HttpHandler wrap(HttpHandler handler) {
                    HttpString[] disallowedHttpMethods = { HttpString.tryFromString("TRACE"),
                        HttpString.tryFromString("TRACK") };
                    return new DisallowedMethodsHandler(handler, disallowedHttpMethods);
                }
            });
        });
    }
}
```